# PowerMock MethodNotFoundException on verifyPrivate with method accepting Class

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

PowerMock throws `org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) methodInsideFoo were found in the class hierarchy of class com.something.Something.`.

Test code:

```
    Something spied = spy(new Something());

    doNothing().when( spied, "methodInsideFoo", "ABC", Some.class );

    spied.foo( "ABC", Some.class );

    verifyPrivate( spied ).invoke( "methodInsideFoo", "ABC", Some.class );
```

And this is the method I'm trying to mock:

```
protected void methodInsideFoo ( String a, Class b )
{
    System.out.println("Should not see me");
}
```

**But if I remove Class (2nd parameter), it works.** Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be related to:

http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=342

[PowerMock, mockito, verify static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285734/powermock-mockito-verify-static-method)

Comment: Maybe, but since the first link is no longer working I cannot know for sure.